# how to pass sysrefcursor as a parameter to oracle scheduler job

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dbms-scheduler

I'm getting a SYSREFCUROSOR as output parameter from a stored procedure, How to call that SP in a oracle scheduler job and pass that parameter?

Comment: What do you plan to do with the ref cursor that is generated? What will use/consume it?

Comment: Maybe write a function which returns your RefCursor and call this function inside your scheduler job.

Comment: just we will call that stored procedure in job. We don't consume it inside the job

Comment: You can't pass around a cursor between different sessions.  Please show some code or pseudo-code, as it it not clear what you are attempting.

Comment: This is my procedure :
create or replace PROCEDURE CSIP_GETRECORDS_SP
  (i_fromdate IN DATE
  ,i_todate   IN DATE
  ,p_result_cur  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  )
  
The cursor will get a set of records between the provided range and that sp is called by the scheduler job and cursor output is used to sent an email.  @OldProgrammer

Comment: Please add code by editing the question, not as a comment. The cursor output will be used by *what* to send an email?

Comment: the cursor output should be used by scheduler_job to send an email @AlexPoole

Comment: You want the *scheduler* to use use your ref cursor when it sends [a notification email](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#CIAFGIHH), as part of the ADD_JOB_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION body argument? That isn't at all clear from the question. And I don't think it's possible. Why not have the procedure send an email itself?

Answer (score 0):

If you are discarding the ref cursor then create a wrapper procedure that does that; something like:

```
create procedure wrapper_proc as
  l_refcursor sys_refcursor;
begin
  orig_proc(l_refcursor);
  close l_refcursor;
end;
/
```

And then call the wrapper procedure in your scheduled job instead.

Comment: But i required that ref cursor value to attach with job and send an email